# Angular 2/Ionic 2, extend ionic component parse errors: More than one component matched on this element

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

### Doubt

I developed an Ionic 2 application and I would like to create extensions for some components already deployed in Ionic 2.

### Example

For example, I create ngModule and try to extends [ionic item](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/item/item.ts)
but retaining its functionality and interaction with other Ionic components. Make `<extended-ion-item>` work like `<ion-item>`, but change `<extended-ion-item>` template and add new functionality.

### Link to the repository with reproduced problem: https://github.com/SonyStone/ionicExtend-issue

`extended-item.ts`

```typescript
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, ElementRef, Renderer, Optional, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

import { Config, Form, ItemReorder, Item } from 'ionic-angular';

import { CopyItem } from './copy-item';

@Component({
    selector: 'extended-ion-item',
    template:
    '<ng-content select="[item-left],ion-checkbox:not([item-right])"></ng-content>' +
    '<div class="item-inner">' +
    '<div class="input-wrapper">' +
    '<ng-content select="ion-label"></ng-content>' +
    '<ion-label *ngIf="_viewLabel">' +
    '<ng-content></ng-content>' +
    '</ion-label>' +
    '<ng-content select="ion-select,ion-input,ion-textarea,ion-datetime,ion-range,[item-content]"></ng-content>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<ng-content select="[item-right],ion-radio,ion-toggle"></ng-content>' +
    '<ion-reorder *ngIf="_shouldHaveReorder"></ion-reorder>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="button-effect"></div>',
    host: {
        'class': 'item'
    },
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class ExtendedItem extends Item {
    constructor(
        form: Form,
        config: Config,
        elementRef: ElementRef,
        renderer: Renderer,
        @Optional() reorder: ItemReorder
    ) {
        super(form, config, elementRef, renderer, reorder);
    }
}
```

`module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { ExtendedItem } from './extended-item';
import { CopyItem } from './copy-item';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        ExtendedItem,
        CopyItem,
    ],
    declarations: [
        ExtendedItem,
        CopyItem,
    ],
})
export class IonicExtensionModule { }
```

### Problem

But I got this error and really do not know how to solve it.

`console`

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
Conflicting components: Item,ExtendedItem ("

<ion-content padding>
    [ERROR ->]<ion-item>
            <ion-avatar item-left>
                <ion-icon name="logo-markdown" style="color: #412159" ></ion"): HomePage@7:1
```

Comment: Please add whole code of  `main.ts`, `module.ts` and `componentName.component.ts`

Comment: this is a shot in the dark but `item.ts` has ` host: {
    'class': 'item'
  },` so maybe set host as `host: {
        'class': 'extended-item'
    }`

Comment: @Mr_Perfect 
all code to see here: https://github.com/SonyStone/ionicExtend-issue;
[main.ts](https://github.com/SonyStone/ionicExtend-issue/blob/master/src/app/main.ts);
[module.ts](https://github.com/SonyStone/ionicExtend-issue/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts);
[*.component.ts](https://github.com/SonyStone/ionicExtend-issue/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @suraj set host as `host: { 'class': 'extended-item' }` nothing changed

Comment: Code related to this `Item` is not there but imported. May be that is the error. Do you have code related to `copy-item` code?

Comment: Only one thing, You shoud have `copy-item.ts` or remove the `Item` from imports

Comment: @Mr_Perfect I use Item from 'ionic-angular', it's look like this:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/item/item.ts

Comment: What about `import { CopyItem } from './copy-item';`?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect CopyItem I try to copy Item component from ionic to my module, it works, but without ionic functionality and styles and it's a lot of copy-paste.

Comment: @Mr_Perfect it's look like this http://i.imgur.com/nceo3n1.png , but I expect look like this http://i.imgur.com/ooU9N2K.png

Comment: Did your error resolved?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect yes, but problem with no inherited functionality from Ionic is still here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's turned out the problem in ionic 2 npm module, where `Item` `@Component` metadata  was stored in `Item.decorators` object, so when I extend `Item`, its metadata inherited too.
So I create `class TempItem extends Item`, clear out metadata, and then `class ExtendedItem extends TempItem`, and it's working now!

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, ElementRef, Renderer, Optional, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

import { Config, Form, ItemReorder, Item } from 'ionic-angular';

class TempItem extends Item {
    static decorators = undefined;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'extended-ion-item',
    templateUrl: './extended-item.html',
    host: {
        'class': 'item item-block'
    },
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class ExtendedItem extends TempItem {
    constructor(
        form: Form,
        config: Config,
        elementRef: ElementRef,
        renderer: Renderer,
        @Optional() reorder: ItemReorder
    ) {

        super(form, config, elementRef, renderer, reorder);
    }
}
```